# How pass JsonObject from Android Activity to javascript

Tags: javascript, android, json, webview

Im' trying to sent a JsonObject from my Android Activity to Webview,in particular i want send the object to Javascript page, how can I do this?

Comment: *how can I do this?* good start should be at https://google.com

Comment: i didn't find any good answer for my problem

Comment: then take the bad one ... seriously, 1. what have you tried so far? and why it wasn't good enough? ... I'm pretty sure that answer is: *1. nothing, I've just ask question here, I'm too lazy* 2: *I did not try anything so: N/A*

Comment: I tryed to pass the object like string with loadUrl, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

A WebView is a ***view*** on the web, like a very simple browser. A WebView can only ***show*** web pages. What you need is any kind of HTTP client. For simple use cases you can use [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). If you want to do something serious, [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) is the easiest way in my opinion.